# How to pass label value to another jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have dynamically loaded data in First.jsp like

```
<label for="hotelName">Hotel Name</label>
```

and when user submits I want to pass some of those to next page(Second.jsp) I use post method. but my data loaded into label. I don't have name attribute to use

```
<% request.getParameter("hotelName"); %>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why you dont print `hotelName` in Hidden Field?

Answer (score 1):

After the label you could make another hidden field and pass the hotel name in that and retreive onto another page like this

```
<label for="hotelName">Hotel Name</label>
<input type="hidden" value="Hotel Name" name="hotelName">
```

and on next page you could use

```
<% request.getParameter("hotelName"); %>
```

Or else you could do this also.
Add hidden fields first only and using jquery pass the label values to the hidden fields

```
<label id="hello">Hello world</label>
<input type="hidden" id="world">
```

and the jquery

```
var value = $("#hello").text(); 
var y = $("#world").val(value);
```